# Parsing an SQL statement to isolate the formulas being used to create the columns after a SELECT statement

Tags: python, sql, parsing, sql-parser

I am trying to parse an SQL statement, the output of which should provide me the formulas to create the columns using attributes from the table that is being ingested using the FROM clause.

Eg.

```
SELECT col1 AS a, SUM((col2/t2.col7 - col9)) AS b, col3 AS c FROM table1 join table2 as t2 
      WHERE col1 in (select col4 from t2)
```

The above statement when parsed should give output as:

---

**Formula**

SUM((col2/t2.col7 - col21))

---

The issue is the formula can contain subqueries which can have further SELECT statements.

Any help is appreciated.